# How to test Spring Batch step without running entire job

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch application that has two steps in a job. I am trying to test each step individually. According to Spring documentation, I should be able to do so using `JobLauncherTestUitls.launchStep()`
I have the following test set up for one of the steps

```
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBatchTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JobConfig.class, EmailAndArchiveStepConfig.class, UpdateFactorReserveConfig.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Testing Email and Archive Configured")
    public void testEmailAndArchiveConfig(){
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("Email and Archive", executionContext);

        assertEquals(new ExitStatus("COMPLETED").getExitCode() ,jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }
```

However, when I run this test, it starts the job from the beginning, running the other step as well, rather than just running this step that I want to test. I have not been able to find any solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

What you are probably seeing is the fact that Spring Boot is running your job by default when you run your test. You can disable that by adding the `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` to your test properties.

Using `jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep` should only launch the step and not the entire job, here is quick self-contained example:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@SpringBatchTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigTest.JobConfig.class)
public class ConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testStep1() {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("step1");
        assertEquals(new ExitStatus("COMPLETED").getExitCode() ,jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public static class JobConfig {

        @Bean
        public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                        System.out.println("hello");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    })
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step step2(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                    .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                        System.out.println("world");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    })
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                    .start(step1(stepBuilderFactory))
                    .next(step2(stepBuilderFactory))
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                    .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                    .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
                    .build();
        }

    }
}
```

This test prints `hello` which means it only launched `step1` and not the entire job. This example does not use Spring Boot and works as expected, which I believe confirms that the behaviour you are seeing is related to the automatic execution of jobs by Spring Boot.

Comment: Note that the HSQL DB libraries in order to create the datasource. And if you're using JUnit5, just replace `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` by `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` and `import org.junit.Test` by `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`